# How to show tags in posts, orderby count(most used) not alphabetically?

Tags: tags

I would like to show most used tags first in single post page, archieve page and on homepage.

**For example:**

I have 4 tags- **Ball**(5 posts), **Doll**(3 posts), **Cat**(2 posts), **Apple**(1 post).
Whenever I put more than one tags in a post, these tags shows in the alphabetical order but I want to show the most used tags first.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by first getting the raw tag data with [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) sorting the results by the `count` property of each tag with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), then looping through them and outputting them as links:

```
/*
 * Get array of tags and sort by count.
 */
$tags = get_the_tags();

if ( $tags && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
    usort( $tags, function( $a, $b ) {
        return $b->count - $a->count; // Swap $a and $b for ascending order.
    } );

    /*
     * Get an HTML link for each tag and put in an array.
     */
    $links = array();

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag ) ) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }

    /*
     * Output links separated by comma.
     */
    echo implode( ', ', $links );
}
```

Another implementation is to create a wrapper of `the_tags()`, that reorders the tags with `wp_list_sort()` via the `get_the_terms` filter:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the tags for a post, ordered by post count.
 *
 * @param string $before Optional. Before list.
 * @param string $sep    Optional. Separate items using this. 
 * @param string $after  Optional. After list.
 */
function the_tags_wpse( $before = null, $sep = ', ', $after = '' ) {
    add_filter( 'get_the_terms', $callback = function( $tags ) {
        return wp_list_sort( $tags, 'count', 'desc' );
    }, 999 );
    the_tags( $before, $sep, $after );
    remove_filter( 'get_the_terms', $callback, 999 );  
}
```

Comment: There's also the [`wp_list_sort()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_sort/) core utility function.

Comment: Added the wrapper implementation as an alternative.